# Swashbuckle.AspNetCore - Is there a way to set the path to swagger.json dynamically?

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I need to host a single service at multiple url's behind an Azure Application Gateway.
The service will be hosted internally at say `http://10.11.12.13:1234` and there will only be a single instance of same.
This needs to be exposed via public URL's like:
- foo.example.com/service1
- bar.example.com/service1 etc.

We can configure Application gateway to rewrite the urls coming in to point to the hosted service. Something like example.com/service1 => 10.11.12.13:1234

The problem is that the path to the swagger file is set in Startup.cs:

```
options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/api/swagger.json", "My API");
```

There is no HttpRequest available at this point so I can't read the headers and configure as appropriate, which is what we do with `PreSerializeFilters` to set the basePath in the returned `swagger.json`.

Currently when a user navigates to `https://foo.example.com/service1/swagger`, the swagger UI will attempt to pull swagger.json down from `https://foo.example.com/swagger/api/swagger.json` which is the wrong location.

It should be pulling from `https://foo.example.com/service1/swagger/api/swagger.json`.

Is there anything similar to `PreSerializeFilters` that I can do to set the path to the swagger.json itself?

Comment: And a setting relative url instead of an absolute one doesn't work?

Comment: It's amazing how often the simplest solution turns out to be the right one - I didn't see the forest for the trees, thanks.  I don't seem to have the option to mark your answer as accepted, but it does indeed solve the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is that the path to the swagger file is set in Startup.cs:
>
> ```
> options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/api/swagger.json", "My API");
> ```

Set an relative url instead of an absolute one.

```
 options.SwaggerEndpoint("swagger/api/swagger.json", "My API");
```